# The difference between :+ and &:+

Tags: ruby

I have code like this

```
 list << num if num.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).map(&:factorial).inject(:+) == num
```

It works, and I was wondering how `inject` works without the `&` (ampersand) in front of the `:+`. I am asking for someone to explain what the differences are between `:+` and `&:+`.

Comment: one of them is wearing a hat?   ...sorry, couldn't resist

Comment: @musefan No, one of them has hairs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&:+` is translated to a proc, while `:+` is a Symbol. [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) supports receiving symbols, which is translated internally to a proc:

> If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is
>   passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element. **If you specify a
>   symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to
>   the named method of memo**. In either case, the result becomes the new
>   value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo
>   is the return value for the method.